# How to implement theming in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I want to create a theme for laravel 5, but not getting any appropriate tutorial for it.

Does anyone knows how to achieve it in laravel 5.

Answer (score 8):

There is a package for managing multiple themes in Laravel 5.

Found here: https://github.com/igaster/laravel-theme

If you want to do it yourself, you can easily achieve it with following steps:

Create a config for your different themes in:

```
// app/config/site.php

return [
    'theme' => 'default'
];
```

create a new folder for your views. One folder for each theme:

```
themes/default/views
themes/other_theme/views
```

And put your blade views file in each directory matching your different themes.

Register which theme the site should use by default:

```
$theme = Config::get('site.theme');
View::addLocation(base_path() . '/themes/' . $theme . '/views/');
```

Additionally you can configure different assets folders for the different themes to compile js and css files with gulp, and so on.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me where i have to create themes folder.

Comment: In the root of your application

Answer (score -2):

there is a very good package to use in

https://github.com/FaCuZ/laravel-theme